# How to fix an error when trying to get the live stream of data from FastAPI using websockets (Unsupported upgrade request.)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, fastapi

How can I get the response for every iteration, like a live stream feed?

Here is the RestAPI `main.py:`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Request
from fastapi import WebSocket
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/ws_res")
async def websoc(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    for i in range(100000):
        i = "John"
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
        await websocket.send_json({"msg": i})
    await websocket.close()
```

Now, I am trying to get the response from python code but I'm receiving an error that says `Unsupported upgrade request.`

Here is the output from API side :

```
INFO:     Started server process [67680]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
WARNING:  Unsupported upgrade request.
```

Here is the python code that I used to access the API (`test.py`):

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    uri = "ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws_res"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {greeting['msg']}")


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "test.py", line 7, in hello
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
  File "/home/test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/client.py", line 517, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "/home/test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/client.py", line 542, in __await_impl__
    await protocol.handshake(
  File "/home/test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/client.py", line 296, in handshake
    raise InvalidStatusCode(status_code)
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 400
```

Comment: Why are you closing the websocket every time you loop?

Comment: @Mause Sorry It was not in the for loop. Small mistake when I copied the code here. Updated

Comment: Have you installed the `websockets` package in the virtual environment you're using for fastapi?

Comment: @Mause Yes I installed it in the same env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastapi websocket endpoints need to be defined using the `websocket` decorator, not the `get` decorator:

```
@app.websocket("/ws_res")
async def websoc(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    for i in range(100000):
        i = "John"
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
        await websocket.send_json({"msg": i})
    await websocket.close()
```

See the documentation for full details: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/